# ¿Como hago que un programa se acabe en un punto en concreto?

Tags: java

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo el cual lo que hace es que imprime un pequeño menu y dependiendo de lo que eliga el usuaio con un "if" "else if" "else" hace una cosa u otra entonces me gustaria que en la opcion de salir osea la 3 en el caso de que hubiese codigo que se ejecutaria despues del if no se ejecutase y se cerrase el programa.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Actividad7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int select;
        System.out.println("Selecciona una de las siguientes opciones");
        System.out.println("1) Saluda");
        System.out.println("2) Saluda 5 veces");
        System.out.println("3) Salir");
        select = input.nextInt();
        if (select == 1){
            System.out.println("Hola, buenos dias");
        }
        else if (select == 2){
            for(int x = 0; x < 5;x++){
                System.out.println("Hola, buenos dias");
            }
        }
        else if (select == 3){
            System.out.println("Adios");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Seleccion incorrecta, para seleccionar pulsa un numero del 1 al 10");
        }
    }
}
```

El codigo funciona correctamente y se puede probar tal y como esta, si alguno sabe como hacer esto lo agradeceria gracias de antemano

Comment: Esta pregunta la podrías haber solucionado haciendo una pequeña búsqueda en google. Te aconsejaría preguntar aquí como última opción, pues debes forzarte a ti mismo a buscar por Internet y a aprender a resolver estos pequeños problemillas. Una opción para terminar el proyecto, podría ser `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: Como bien dice @Manuel, una simple búsqueda en google te habría dado múltiples respuestas válidas. Preguntar en SO sin haber investigado nosotros lo leemos como "Quiero que hagan este trabajo por mi", y sinceramente, nadie va a trabajar para ti aquí. Investigar antes de preguntar ***ES OBLIGATORIO***. Aquí estamos para ayudar, pero si tú no te esfuerzas primero no puede considerarse ayuda si no hacer tu trabajo. Y eso, sinceramente, no te va a servir de nada porque lo más importante que necesitas aprender, es a investigar. No java, no C, ***investigar***.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 else if (select == 3){
       System.out.println("Adios");
       System.exit(0);
 }
```

Comment: Lee [answer], en especial la sección _Contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_. No respondas a una pregunta en donde el autor de la misma no se ha esforzado en investigar antes de redactarla.

Comment: Entendido, me limitare a responder preguntas mas completas y mejor formadas.